# Can't shrink or move linux partition "leftward" in gparted

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted

I have a partition that is completely full, and there is no unallocated space on either side of it to "expand into". So want to shrink one adjacent partition, maybe "scoot" the data over on the partition so that I get more unallocated space for the partition caught in the middle.

In any case, the usual left arrow shown below is not showing up for me. I only have the right arrow. This leaves me unable to accomplish what I want.

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Can you also post a screenshot of the main GParted window (that's hidden) so we can see exactly which partition you're trying to shrink or move?

Answer (score 0):

I was using gparted while it the partitions were in use, rather than booting from a USB or CD. Once I did that, both arrows show up.

TLDR I had a homer simpson moment.